# SWI-Prolog C# iterating through List as a Result

Tags: c#, prolog, swi-prolog

I have in my file a few predicates.

```
cam_curto(User1,User2,Cam):-cam_curto(User1,User2,[User1],Cam).
cam_curto(User1,User1,LA,Cam):-reverse(LA,Cam).
cam_curto(User1,User2,LA,Cam):- liga(User1,Z,_,_), \+ member(Z,LA), cam_curto(Z,User2,[Z|LA],Cam).

mais_curto(UserA,UserB,CamCurto):- findall((Tam,Caminho),(cam_curto(UserA,UserB,Caminho),length(Caminho,Tam)),LSol), sort(LSol,LSolOrd),reverse(LSolOrd , ListaFinal), ListaFinal=[(_,CamCurto)|_],!.
```

The real doubt is not about the prolog in itself because we tested it and it works!

But in my C# app I want to call the predicate `mais_curto(UserA,UserB,CamCurto)`

`CamCurto` being a list with the shortest path between the 2 users.

In C# how can I get the result list?

```
public static List<int> caminhoMaisCurto(int iduser1, int iduser2)
        {
            List<int> ret = new List<int>();

            PlQuery q = new PlQuery("cam_curto(" + iduser1 + "," + iduser2 + ",C).");

            foreach(PlTermV v in q.Solutions)
            {

            }

            return ret;
        }
```

The foreach just runs forever and never stops! I don't know why. I tried so many things but I think this is the right approach. Can someone help me?

Comment: How many elements are there in `q.Solutions`?

Comment: That's the point. It never stops. I tried the Solutions.Count() and it goes infinite. I really don't know how I'm gonna receive the list from Prolog.